# Get Count Between Comma and First Character

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my table, the values appear like this in a column:

```
Names
----------------
Doe,John P
Woods, Adam
Hart,     Keeve
Hensen,Sarah J
```

Is it possible to get a count of space between the comma and first character after it? Expected result:

```
Names            |Count_of_spaces_before_next_character
-----------------|--------------------------------------
Doe,John P       |                    0
Woods, Adam      |                    1
Hart,     Keeve  |                    5
Hensen,Sarah J   |                    0
```

Thanks for any direction, much appreciate it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove everything up to the comma and then measure the length after trimming off the spaces:

```
select len(rest) - len(ltrim(rest))
from t cross apply
     (values (stuff(name, 1, charindex(',', name + ','), ''))
     ) v(rest);
```

The `+ ','` handles the case where there is no comma in `name`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d6ae303457b62e0521656847ecac8154) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Is it optimal to use cross apply on large data? I'm not familiar , thanks

Comment: @Stefano . . . Yes, especially in this case where it is merely creating a new column.  It should have the same execution plan as a subquery that defines `rest`.  It should prevent executing the expression twice.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz . . . Using a subquery to define `rest` instead of `apply`.

Answer (score 2):

You may try with the following statement:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (Names varchar(1000))
INSERT INTO Data 
   (Names)
VALUES
   ('Doe,John P'),
   ('Woods, Adam'),
   ('Hart,     Keeve'),
   ('Hensen,Sarah J')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT Names, LEN(After) - LEN(LTRIM(After)) AS [Count]
FROM (
   SELECT 
      Names, 
      RIGHT(Names, LEN(Names) - CHARINDEX(',', Names)) AS After
   FROM Data   
) t
```

Result:

```
Names          Count
Doe,John P         0
Woods, Adam        1
Hart,     Keeve    5
Hensen,Sarah J     0
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

Even shorter & Cleaner

```
select names
      ,patindex('%[^ ]%',stuff(names,1,charindex(',',names),''))-1 as Count_of_spaces_before_next_character

from   mytab
```

-

```
+----------------+---------------------------------------+
|     names      | Count_of_spaces_before_next_character |
+----------------+---------------------------------------+
| Doe,John P     |                                     0 |
| Woods, Adam    |                                     1 |
| Hart, Keeve    |                                     5 |
| Hensen,Sarah J |                                     0 |
| Hello World    |                                     0 |
+----------------+---------------------------------------+
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9cce1/18/0)

Answer (score 0):

Building off of Gordon's answer. If you are not familiar with table constructor approach in `cross apply`, you might find this more readable. Hope the `select` in `cross apply` clears your confusion around how it can behave like a `subquery`. Also, I don't think you need to pad the name column with an additional `','` because `charindex` will return 0 if it doesn't find that character.

```
select name, len(rest) - len(ltrim(rest))
from t1
cross apply (select stuff(name, 1, charindex(',', name), '') as rest) t2
```

Answer (score -1):

Logic: LEN(string after first comma) - LEN(LTRIM(string after first comma))

```
SELECT Name, LEN (SUBSTRING(Names,CHARINDEX(',',Names,1)+1 ,LEN(Names) - CHARINDEX(',',Names,1)) ) - LEN(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Names,CHARINDEX(',',Names,1)+1 , LEN(Names) - CHARINDEX(',',Names,1))))
FROM #Table
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.